# Why is KMeans a class rather than a function defined in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

From developers' perspective, why did they design [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) using a class and let people init it and use it like this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0], [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
```

Why not a function so that users can import and call it directly?

Comment: If I have to guess it is because KMeans does not provide only one function. After one has fitted the KMeans one is able to call another function, maybe most important `predict` to use the KMeans clustering to predict on a  new dataset. When KMeans was a function you have to fit KMeans and use that output to predict based on the output of the fit. But I am curious what other think about this question, since I am oftem struggling when writing code to decide how to chose between creating a class or a function.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the `scikit-learn` design pattern works, almost all of the models are classes, for each class, we have functions like `predict`, and `fit`.

In fact, for any machine learning model, there must be some internal states, weights for an MLP model for example, if you want to manage these states in a managed way, a class should be your first choice, not a function.